# off focus event on text field - extjs 4.1 mvc

Tags: extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

When the user is finished typing into a textfield i would like to call an event.

Currently i have

```
'#ClientId': { change: this.onProjectItemSelect },
```

The event 'change' is called, but it is called when the user starts typing.

I appreciate this is standard question for the docs. Where is the event info documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **blur** event:

> Fires when this Component loses focus.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-blur

(The documentation of the textfield component: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text)